# Can i have a second cable modem in my house to be able to have ethernet in two diffrent rooms?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I have a Computer that i want to connect to ethernet but my computer is upstairs and my cable modem is down stairs, are there any conflicts from buying another cable modem and putting a second one upstairs and connecting my computer to that modem via ethernet? Is this a good solution?

Comment: If you want to use two cable modems this would require you pay your ISP for that ability.  Your second cable modem wouldn't connect to your ISP's network until you paid them for that ability.  Wouldn't it be easier to just move the first modem?

Comment: Why not just extend the cable and directly connect the Ethernet to the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can run Ethernet cable through the walls, you don't need another cable modem. If you have a [network switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_switch) or [router](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28computing%29) downstairs with a free Ethernet port on the [LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network) side, you can run Ethernet cabling through the walls from upstairs to downstairs that plugs into your downstairs switch or router. Running [cabling through walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riser_cable) is not something most home users undertake. If you are in the U.S., you can buy the cabling, RJ45 connectors, face plates, wall box, crimping tool, [flexible drill bit](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Milwaukee-1-2-in-x-72-in-Cable-Bit-48-13-8350/203115401) for drilling behind walls, etc. from [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/) and do the work yourself or you could pay someone to do that work for you, e.g., an electrician or a company that specializes in providing networking services. Most home users, though, will opt for the easier solution of just using a Wi-Fi connection to connect a computer in one room with a wireless router in another room. Or, if for some reason you don't wish to use a wireless connection, you could use [powerline networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerline_networking), i.e., you purchase two small boxes that plug into your electrical outlets. You plug one into an electrical outlet in each room and then run an Ethernet cable from your computer to the box in the room where the computer is located and another Ethernet cable from the box in the outlet where your current cable modem is located to a router or switch in that room. See [How Power-line Networking Works](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/power-network.htm) for a fuller explanation of how it works.

Otherwise, as Ramhound pointed out, if you want another cable modem connection from your ISP you will incur a monthly cost for the second Internet service into your home.